# Java: a variable "might have already been initialized", but I don't understand how

Tags: java, final

First some context: all the code pasted below is within another class declared as `public class TheClass extends SomeProprietaryClass`. I cannot declare these classes in another file for various reasons... And log messages are in French. And I'm a "final happy" kind of programmer. Which is at the core of the problem here...

Now, the code... (probably too much of it -- stripping on demand to only keep the relevant parts)

A custom Exception:

```
private static final class BreadCrumbException
    extends Exception
{
    private BreadCrumbException(final String message)
    {
        super(message);
    }

    private BreadCrumbException(final String message, final Throwable cause)
    {
        super(message, cause);
    }
}
```

An enum for "materializing" the visibility of a breadcrumb element:

```
private enum Visibility
{
    MAINPAGE("R"),
    MENU("M"),
    BREADCRUMB("A"),
    COMMERCIAL("C");

    private static final Map<String, Visibility> reverseMap
        = new HashMap<String, Visibility>();

    private static final String characterClass;

    static {
        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("[");

        for (final Visibility v: values()) {
            reverseMap.put(v.flag, v);
            sb.append(v.flag);
        }

        sb.append("]");
        characterClass = sb.toString();
    }

    private final String flag;

    Visibility(final String flag)
    {
        this.flag = flag;
    }

    static EnumSet<Visibility> fromBC(final String element)
    {
        final EnumSet<Visibility> result = EnumSet.noneOf(Visibility.class);

        for (final String s: reverseMap.keySet())
            if (element.contains(s))
                result.add(reverseMap.get(s));

        return result;
    }


    static String asCharacterClass()
    {
        return characterClass;
    }

    static String asString(final EnumSet<Visibility> set)
    {
        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for (final Visibility v: set)
            sb.append(v.flag);

        return sb.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return flag;
    }
}
```

A breadcrumb element:

```
private static class BreadCrumbElement
{
    private static final Pattern p
        = Pattern.compile(String.format("(%s+)(\\d+)",
        Visibility.asCharacterClass()));

    private final String element;
    private final String menuID;
    private final EnumSet<Visibility> visibility;

    BreadCrumbElement(final String element)
    {
        final Matcher m = p.matcher(element);

        if (!m.matches())
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Élément de fil d'ariane invalide: " + element);

        this.element = element;
        visibility = EnumSet.copyOf(Visibility.fromBC(m.group(1)));
        menuID = m.group(2);
    }

    public boolean visibleFrom(final Visibility v)
    {
        return visibility.contains(v);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(final Object o)
    {
        if (this == o)
            return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass())
            return false;

        final BreadCrumbElement that = (BreadCrumbElement) o;

        return element.equals(that.element);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode()
    {
        return element.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return element;
    }

    public String getMenuID()
    {
        return menuID;
    }
}
```

A breadcrumb:

```
private static class BreadCrumb
    implements Iterable<BreadCrumbElement>
{
    private static final BreadCrumb EMPTY = new BreadCrumb();

    private final List<BreadCrumbElement> elements
        = new LinkedList<BreadCrumbElement>();

    private String bc;

    BreadCrumb(final String bc)
        throws BreadCrumbException
    {
        final Set<BreadCrumbElement> set = new HashSet<BreadCrumbElement>();
        BreadCrumbElement e;

        for (final String element: bc.split("\\s+")) {
            e = new BreadCrumbElement(element);
            if (!set.add(e))
                throw new BreadCrumbException("Élément dupliqué "
                    + "dans le fil d'Ariane : " +  element);
            elements.add(e);
        }

        if (elements.isEmpty())
            throw new BreadCrumbException("Fil d'ariane vide!");

        if (!elements.get(0).visibleFrom(Visibility.MAINPAGE))
            throw new BreadCrumbException("Le fil d'Ariane ne "
                + "commence pas à l'accueil : " + bc);

        set.clear();
        this.bc = bc;
    }

    private BreadCrumb()
    {
    }

    BreadCrumb reverse()
    {
        final BreadCrumb ret = new BreadCrumb();
        ret.elements.addAll(elements);
        Collections.reverse(ret.elements);
        ret.bc = StringUtils.join(ret.elements, " ");
        return ret;
    }

    public Iterator<BreadCrumbElement> iterator()
    {
        return elements.iterator();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return bc;
    }
}
```

The interface to a breadcrumb renderer:

```
public interface BreadCrumbRender
{
    List<CTObjectBean> getBreadCrumb()
        throws Throwable;

    String getTopCategory();

    String getMenuRoot();

    String getContext();
}
```

The implementation of the interface above which is the source of my problems:

```
private class CategoryBreadCrumbRender
    implements BreadCrumbRender
{
    private final BreadCrumb bc;
    private final CTObject object;

    CategoryBreadCrumbRender(final CTObject object)
    {
        this.object = object;
        final String property;

        // FIELD_BC is declared as a private static final String earlier on.
        // logger is also a private static final Logger
        try {
            property = object.getProperty(FIELD_BC);
        } catch (Throwable throwable) {
            logger.fatal("Impossible d'obtenir le champ " + FIELD_BC
                + " de l'objet", throwable);
            bc = BreadCrumb.EMPTY;
            return;
        }

        try {
            bc = new BreadCrumb(property);
        } catch (BreadCrumbException e) {
            logger.fatal("Impossible d'obtenir le fil d'Ariane", e);
            bc = BreadCrumb.EMPTY; // <-- HERE
        }
    }
    // ....
```

At the point marked `// <-- HERE` above, Intellij IDEA, which I use, and javac (1.6.0.29) both tell me that `Variable bc might already have been assigned to`, which is considered an error (and indeed, the code does not compile).

Trouble is, I do not understand why... My reasoning is the following:

- in the first try/catch block (and yes, `.getProperty()` does throw Throwable), when an exception is caught, `bc` gets assigned to successfully, and then I return, so far so good;
- in the second try/catch block, the constructor may fail, in which case I assign an empty breadcrumb, so it should be OK, even though `bc` is final: the assignment doesn't happen (?) in the try block but happens in the catch block instead...

Except no, it doesn't. As both IDEA and javac disagree with me, they are certainly right. But why?

(and also, `BreadCrumb.EMPTY` is declared `private static final` in the class, I wonder how come I can access it at all... Subsidiary question)

**EDIT**: there is a known bug with the `final` keyword ([here](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6326693), thanks to @MiladNaseri for linking to it), however it should be noted that in this bug, variable `v` is only ever assigned in `catch` blocks -- but in the code above, I assign it in `try` blocks and only assign it in `catch` blocks if an exception is thrown. Also, it should be noted that the error only occurs in the second `catch` block.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, suppose that in the first try block, when doing `property = object.getProperty(FIELD_BC);` an exception occurs. So, JVM will enter the catch block, and initialize `bc` along the way.

Then in the second try block, also an exception occurs, resulting in `BreadCrumb.EMPTY` being assigned to `bc`, effectively overriding its original value.

Now, that is how `bc` *might* have already been initialized. I hope you see where I'm coming from.

Since the JAVAC analysis engine does not draw a distinction between one or many statements inside the try block, it does not see your case any different than the below:

```
try {
    bc = null;
    String x = null;
    System.out.println(x.toString());
} catch (Throwable e) {
    bc = null;
}
```

In which case, `bc` **will** be assigned twice. In other words, JAVAC won't care that where the source of the `Throwable` lies, it only cares that it can be there, and that `bc` might undergo a successful assignment in that try block.

Comment: +1  Yes, that's it.  You need to make a local variable localBC, and, at the very end, assign it to bc once and only once.

Comment: Exactly. That's the way around the warning.

Comment: Yes. But the flow control algorithm leading to that warning is kind of iffy about return statements. You can see that for yourself. Place a return statement in the middle of a method and you get unreachable code error. Then put an always-true condition before it and you're set (even if the condition is an exception that can never happen).

Comment: You should also note that this is a [known bug](http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6326693).

Comment: Define "kind of iffy"? And it's an error, the code does not compile... I mean, I do assign `bc` in the first `catch` block and `return`, with no problems. Then I "try" and assign it in the second `try` block: if the `BreadCrumb` constructor fails, `bc` is not assigned and then it should be assigned in the `catch` block...

Comment: Iffy here means buggy. It does not realize that in a well defined situation `bc` could not be assigned more than once. To avoid the error, you have to evaluate the value for `bc` using an intermediary variable and then assign it to `bc`. Also, there's another situation which might result in the error, which I'll be adding to the answer right away.

Comment: @MiladNaseri after reading the bug, I don't really think it relates to my use case -- in the bug report, the variable is _only assigned in catch blocks_. This is not my case...

Comment: Yes, you are right. That bug doesn't exactly relate to this error. [This thread](http://www.coderanch.com/t/523977/java/java/final-field-may-already-have), though, does. I added the extra information. I hope I've been thorough.

Comment: You won't necessarily need to. I've added the gist to my answer.

Comment: @MiladNaseri I'm afraid I don't see the gist in question... You seem to have a better grasp than I, even after I have read the thread and IBM's page, what's more your first paragraph still doesn't seem to account for the fact that I return in the first catch block. Care to elaborate the answer?

Comment: Of course. Suppose that in the first try block no errors occur, so `bc` is still uninitialized. Then you reach the second try block, in which `bc` might or might not be initialized (because JAVAC cannot know when or where an exception might occur), so when it reaches the assignment inside the catch block, it cannot be sure if it's been already initialized or not. Also, this error ensures that you leave the constructor with exactly one executable assignment statement for the final variable. You don't grasp it easily, because you KNOW that the try block is there just for the assignment.

Comment: But if it was accompanied by a second statement, say, `String x = null; System.out.println(x.toString());` then *that* statement might have been the cause of the Exception, leaving `bc` initialized, and then jumping to the `catch` block where it would be again assigned a new value.
However, JAVAC cannot so easily assume that the catch block is there just for that one assignment, and for that special situation ignore the possibility of such an error.

Comment: @MiladNaseri OK, thanks for your time. I ended up using a temporary variable and only one catch block (god do I _hate_ APIs throwin Throwable), but you helped me a great deal understanding what happens here! Out of curiosity I'll probably try a few test classes with checked/unchecked exceptions etc and see what's what... Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the analysis is deep enough to really understand that there is only one statement in the try block, and the diagnostic is issued no matter what, so that's why you're seeing it in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
BreadCrumb tmp = null;
try {
    tmp = new BreadCrumb(property);
} catch (BreadCrumbException e) {
    logger.fatal("Impossible d'obtenir le fil d'Ariane", e);
    tmp = BreadCrumb.EMPTY;
}
bc = tmp;
```